# QtGui.QSystemTrayIcon settooltip not working in debian stretch

Tags: python, linux, qt, debian, pyqt4

The following code works well in debian jessie but not in debian stretch.
The code displays the icon in system tray. in Jessie, it shows the toolstip correctly, but in Debian Stretch, the tool tip text appears as file name, not what I have set to.

Not sure what kind of debugging I can do here and to know what could be the issue.
It is using 
python 2.7.9 in debian jessie 
python 2.7.13 in debian stretch

```
#!/usr/bin/python -u

import sys
from PyQt4 import QtGui, QtCore

import signal
signal.signal(signal.SIGINT, signal.SIG_DFL)

def main():
   app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)

   trayIcon = QtGui.QSystemTrayIcon(QtGui.QIcon('test.png'), app)
   menu = QtGui.QMenu()
   exitAction = menu.addAction("Exit")
   trayIcon.setContextMenu(menu)

   trayIcon.setToolTip('test tool tip')

   trayIcon.show()
   sys.exit(app.exec_())

if __name__ == '__main__':
   main()
```

Comment: Any help on this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This looked like a qt4 issue. pyqt5 + python3 resolved it.
Debian stretch uses KDE 5 which is based on  KDE 5 (Plasma) architecture. Converting the program to python3 with pyqt5 resolved the issue

```
#!/usr/bin/python3 -u

import sys
from PyQt5 import QtGui, QtCore,QtWidgets
from PyQt5 import Qt

import signal
signal.signal(signal.SIGINT, signal.SIG_DFL)

def main():
   app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)

   w = QtWidgets.QWidget()
   trayIcon = QtWidgets.QSystemTrayIcon(QtGui.QIcon('test.png'), w)
   menu = QtWidgets.QMenu()
   exitAction = menu.addAction("Exit")
   trayIcon.setContextMenu(menu)

   trayIcon.setToolTip('test tool tip')

   trayIcon.show()
   sys.exit(app.exec_())

if __name__ == '__main__':
   main()
```